# how to achieve this css3 shadow effect?

Tags: shadow, css

I am trying to see if its possible to achieve this kind of shadow using pure css3:

[image]

I quickly mocked this up in photoshop. I am looking for that curved shadow effect. I know its possible to get straigt shadow effects. I tried to look on google I dont even know what to call that curved shadow. I couldn't find anywhere that says its not possible. Couldnt find anywhere that says it IS possible either.

if css3 isn't happening, I am willing to use jQuery.

any help, much appreciated. 
thanks.

edit: The closest I've gotten to achieve any sort of shadow just with css3 is this: http://jsfiddle.net/tVt4w/

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/ http://www.matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html You can easily adapt those techniques to make the shadow you show, although I personally think yours is a bit over the top. Entirely possible though.

Comment: Hi Lea,  I am just working on a personal portfolio, so its good to be a bit over the top there :) right?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry. Good design is subtle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At first I didn't think it was possible. Then I found [this page](http://snipplr.com/view/52286/different-css-dropshadows/) that shows some nice examples in pure css.

Nifty.

See the [demo page](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/) for an idea of what can be achieved.

Comment: Nice. Of course, none of this works in IE (including 9.)  Sigh.

Comment: It's not working in IE though.

Comment: Hi, I found some other page listing the first example from your link, but not the whole thing. I am checking other styles from your link, will let you know how it goes in a bit, thanks very much.

Comment: Lifted corners!! that's exactly what I wanted, will meddle with it until I "lift" the corners to my liking, thanks so much! now for everybody's favourite little devil IE, do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: Hey, just curious did you get anything working for IE?

Comment: Found a few hacks, but none with the rounded edge effect. [Maybe this could be a comprimise](http://ole-laursen.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-css3-box-shadow-with-ie.html), because I doubt IE will integrate CSS3 shadow properties anytime soon.

Comment: @stefgosselin, its working in IE9 with no problems, but not in any thing else (IE). So still looking around for options, if my client says (He uses chrome) its okay then I wont bother with it but I am looking at it anyway.

Comment: oh, I did find a post on getting things to work in IE8 (it had a lot of ``ms-fitler`` and some ridiculous options)

Answer (score 2):

### HTML and CSS only

The shadow automatically adapts to the width of the image.

Using a PNG image, this can be done:

(not exhaustively tested for compatibility but it works in the latest FF, Safari and Chrome)

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.shadow {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
}
.arch01:after {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0; margin:0;
    height:34px;
    width:100%;
    bottom:-30px;
    left:0px; right:0px;
    background-image: url('arch_01.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position:left top;
}
</style>


<span class="shadow arch01">
    <img src="photo.jpg" width="500px" height="250px">
</span>
```

Comment: No, sorry... It's not "html and css only" if you're using an image, is it?

Comment: Since images are part of the first implementation of HTML in 1993, then no, I disagree.
Images are more fundamental than css itself.
This is quite simplified, but if pure core compatibility is your goal, then the best alternative is to dump css, go back to tables and slot in a shadow image in a table cell under the image or box you wish to have the shadow fall under.