# How to create a shadow box in css3

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for ways to create a shadow box as below. Looked up various tutorials online and can't seem to get it working.

[image]

I am trying to create a shadow box as above for my website, but i dont know how to get the number of pixels right for the center of the box.

How should the CSS3 be? Any help would be great in helping me.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you can use box-shadow css property for that.

Comment: Yes i know, but im trying to get the box shadow to not appear in the bottom middle of the box as shown in the picture. Just finding it hard to remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to achieve this css3 shadow effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190827/how-to-achieve-this-css3-shadow-effect)

Comment: I've marked a duplicate question, which asked for pretty much the same effect, and has answers that link to several sites with good examples.  Another example here: http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2789364) that I did a year ago.

And this [**simplified version**](http://dabblet.com/gist/5124442) that I did right now.

**HTML**: `<div class="box"></div>`

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.box {
    width: 20em; height: 6em;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}
.box:before, .box:after {
    min-height: 45%; width: 65%;
    border-radius: .2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 .625em rgba(204,204,204,.4);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(204,204,204,.4);
    content: '';
}
.box:before {
    bottom: 0; left: .3em;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
.box:after {
    right: .3em; bottom: 0; 
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

You don't need to get the number of pixels. You can use `%` values.

Answer (score 1):

The technique is applied to a single element. A couple of pseudo-elements are generated from this element and then pushed behind it , like `#box:before, #box:after` . These pseudo elements are than positioned explicitly .
You then have to apply the css3 box shadow to these elements and apply transforms.
Read more about them on the following sites :

http://nimbupani.com/drop-shadows-with-css3.html
http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/
Also the below code is from http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow
The Html

```
<div id="box">
   <p>Content and content</p>
</div>
```

The css :

```
 #box 
  {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #ddd;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 60px auto;
    }


  #box:before, #box:after 
  {
  z-index: -1; 
  position: absolute; 
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%; 
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);   
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);    
 -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);   
 -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
   }

#box:after 
{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In html5, there's the box-shadow property for producing such shadows...
Earlier it required flash or photoshop to create such a thing...

This should be helpful: It has all the other features too...

http://w3schools.com/css3/default.asp

Answer (score -3):

This kind of shadow is not so far possible in CSS3, the solution to this is by creating an external image of shadow and then apply it the background-image to the element.

Also you can find Photoshop actions for creating realistic shadows, then use it as the background image to add depth..